# Prove $\frac{\bar z}{z^2}-\frac{z}{\bar z^2}$ is a pure imaginary number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> I have come across the intriguing statement that $\frac{\bar z}{z^2}-\frac{z}{\bar z^2}$ is an imaginary number, but somehow - no matter what I try - I cannot seem to get to that result (I have tried a long list of operations, but all of the outcomes still had the 'a' of 'a+ib' or 'a-ib' in it in the end). Can anybody shed some light on this?

Thank you!

Comment: You mean pure imaginary?  Well...take it's complex conjugate.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$\frac{\overline{z}}{z^2} = a+ib.$$
Then
$$\overline{\left(\frac{\overline{z}}{z^2}\right)} =\frac{z}{\overline{z}^2}= a-ib.$$
Consequently,
$$\frac{\overline{z}}{z^2} - \frac{z}{\overline{z}^2} = ?$$

Comment: Thanks! Could you just explain the rule on which the second equation is based? How do you know that z(bar)/z^2 = z/z(bar)^2? I cannot find it anywhere in my book...

Comment: I think the rule is $\overline{x\cdot y} = \overline{x} \cdot \overline{y}$ and $\overline{\overline{x}}=x$. You can easily verify them.

Comment: @Pregunto Babelfish has mentioned the rules.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\frac{\overline{z}}{z^2}-\frac{z}{\overline{z}^2} = \frac{\overline{z}^3-z^3}{z^2\overline{z}^2}$ (1). You should know that $z\overline{z} = \lvert z\rvert \in \mathbb{R}$. By consequence, the denominator of (1) is real. To prove that your expression is imaginary now comes down to proving that the numerator of (1) is imaginary. From here on it should be a lot easier. The conclusion of the proof is in the spoiler.

> It is now useful to write $z=a+ib$, with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. The numerator of (1) then becomes $(a^3-ia^2b-ab^2+ib^3)-(a^3+ia^2b-ab^2-ib^3) = -2ia^2b+2ib^3$, which is completely imaginary. We are done.

Comment: So that's the thing: I got that far, but then I assumed that the real denominator keeps the number real. So that was a wrong assumption?

Comment: Consider $\frac{ia}{b}$. The denominator is real and the enumerator is imaginary. This number is of course equal to $i\frac{a}{b}$, which is imaginary ($i$ times the real number $\frac{a}{b}$). That assumption was wrong. It might be useful to think about how you came to that assumption, it could clear things up and lead to a better understanding.

Comment: Now I get it… thanks!